# A simple word embedder only using jax

Tags: python, ai, neural-network

How can this code be improved? I'm a novice programmer trying to learn ml by doing it from scratch. This code is part of a transformer model that I'm working on. Do you have any ideas about how to improve it for better performance and easier reality?

```
import jax

import jax.numpy as jnp

class Embedding():

    def __init__(self, vocab_size, d_model, learning_rate=0.01, decay_steps=100, decay_rate=0.9):
        self.vocab_size = vocab_size
        self.d_model = d_model
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.decay_steps = decay_steps
        self.decay_rate = decay_rate
        self.global_step = 0

    def __call__(self, x):
        return jnp.take(jnp.eye(self.vocab_size), x, axis=0)

    def weights_init(self):
        key = jax.random.PRNGKey(0)
        self.embedding_matrix = jax.random.normal(key, (self.vocab_size, self.d_model))
        key = jax.random.PRNGKey(1)
        self.context_matrix = jax.random.normal(key, (self.d_model, self.vocab_size))

    def forward(self, x):
        # Embedding layer
        # x is a vector of size (vocab_size, 1)
        # embedding_matrix is a matrix of size (vocab_size, d_model)
        # hidden is a vector of size (d_model, 1)
        hidden = jnp.dot(self.embedding_matrix.T, x)
        # Context layer
        # context_matrix is a matrix of size (d_model, vocab_size)
        # output is a vector of size (vocab_size, 1)
        output = jnp.dot(self.context_matrix.T, hidden)
        # Using softmax as activation function
        prediction = jax.nn.softmax(output)
        return hidden, prediction

    def backward(self, hidden, prediction, label):
        # Calculate error
        error = jnp.array(label) - prediction

        # Calculate cross-entropy loss
        loss = -jnp.sum(jnp.array(label) * jnp.log(prediction))

        # Calculate gradient
        grad_context = jnp.dot(hidden, error.T)
        grad_embedding = jnp.dot(error, self.context_matrix.T)

        self.loss = loss
        self.update_weights(grad_context, grad_embedding)



    def update_weights(self, grad_context, grad_embedding):
        # Update weights
        self.context_matrix += self.learning_rate * grad_context
        self.embedding_matrix += self.learning_rate * grad_embedding

        # Update learning rate
        self.global_step += 1
        if self.global_step % self.decay_steps == 0:
            self.learning_rate = self.learning_rate * self.decay_rate
```

Comment: In `weights_init()` you make the curious suggestion that the PRNG is in a non-deterministic state and must therefore be re-seeded prior to creating `context_matrix`. Other than that, the code reads like it was faithfully typed in from a nice text book. "_How can this code be improved?_" You gave us barely  a smidgen of Review Context. We don't know your use case, your automated test suite, nor your evaluation rubric, so absent any obvious stack trace bugs we can't nudge this code in an "improved" direction, since you haven't described what's sub-optimal about it.